# Deleted entire Git project

Tags: git

I tried to fix my git repo and .gitignore for not having tracked the right files and everything is gone from remote and from local. This is some history of commands in bash on my ubuntu server:

```
 1952  git status
 1955  git rm -r --cached .

 1957  git commit -m "git fix"
 1958  git push

 1981  git rm -rf data/
 1982  git rm -r --cached data
 1983  git clean -xdf

 1986  git ls-files
 1995  ls
```

The major issue is everything is gone locally or remotely.
Thanks and Regards,

Comment: I still have .git in the project directory

Comment: ```git ls-files``` shows nothing. Also ```git status``` shows working directory clean, up to date with ```origin/master```

Comment: If Git still has your files, they are in its _commits_. So if there is a previous commit, they might be in it. What does `git log --oneline --all --graph` say? — Or, as an experiment, just say `git checkout @~` and see whether at least some of your files come back.

Comment: However, if the commit you just made is the _first_ commit you've ever made, then the files are well and truly gone; `rm` means `rm`, `clean` means `clean`.

Comment: @matt ```git checkout @~``` worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ```git status``` shows HEAD detached at ba01c3f. I am missing 2 files which were not pushed to the repo. Also all the files have a new timestamp and are 3 minutes old.

Comment: Detached head and new timestamps are normal. The two files that are lost might be lost forever, unless they were committed to an earlier commit; you will have to figure that one out yourself, but don't hope for much.

Comment: To fix the detached head, `git reset HEAD`. You will then be abandoning the old head, you understand, so if it happens to contain any files at all that you care about, retrieve them manually now, because that commit will vanish eventually.

Comment: "But why the files are not there locally?" Because that's not what these commands do. They delete the actual visible files from the working tree. And they don't just hide them; they wipe them, kaboom. If your goal was only to clean the index, that is `git restore` or a form of `git reset`.

Comment: I summarized our findings as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Git commands are "dangerous": they wipe out actual files from the world of your visible files (the *working tree*). And they do not just conceal them in some tricky way; they just remove them, as if they had never been. You have chosen to use two of those commands: `git clean` and `git rm`.

So if you use those commands, you can certainly remove files in such a way that they can never ever be recovered.

However, the job of Git is to preserve earlier states of your working tree. So if you made any commits that included any state of any of these files, then those states are preserved in those commits. So all you have to do is one or both of these:

- return to an earlier commit that includes your files
- extract an individual file from an earlier commit that includes it

Since everything was pretty much okay in the commit before the one you just made, you can go back to that commit simply by saying

```
git checkout @~
```

If you're pretty happy with what you see, then you will also want to get out of detached head mode by resetting your branch to what you see now:

```
git reset HEAD
```

But if there are other files that were in your working tree and have *never* been committed, then that is no business of Git's and no fault of Git's: you are the one who used the very dangerous words `clean` and `rm`, so whatever you damage you did, you did it to yourself. Git only stores *commits*; that is all it knows about and all it cares about.

So what's the lesson here? Is it "don't ever give dangerous commands"? Not at all! Give any commands you like, but *first* you need to be *safe*. To preserve a file (meaning a file in a particular state), commit it — and do that *before* you start rattling around giving dangerous commands. To risk losing a file when you give dangerous commands, don't commit it. It's as simple as that.